# recaptcha v3 everytime says im a robot

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to integrate recpatcha v3 to my website. The problem is, when I click on the submit button, it always goes to the "you are a robot" condition.
Here's my code:

```
define('SITE_KEY', 'my site key here');
define('SECRET_KEY', 'my secret key here');

if($_POST){
  function getCaptcha($SecretKey){
    $Response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".SECRET_KEY."&response={$SecretKey}");
    $Return = json_decode($Response);
    return $Return;
  }
  $Return = getCaptcha($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
  if($Return->succes == true && $Return->score > 0.5){
    echo "Succes!";
  } else {
    echo "You are a Robot! :(";
  }
}
```

A hidden input in my form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response"/>
```

and the javascript:

```
<script>
function onClick(e) {
e.preventDefault();
grecaptcha.ready(function() {
grecaptcha.execute('<?php echo SITE_KEY; ?>', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').value=token;
});
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: You have `success` in `$Return->succes` spelled wrong. Is this a typo in the code you pasted or is that how you actually have it spelled in your code?

Comment: Tbh I don't really understand that line. I was following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zGNH_lbpmm8 but you are right, I spelled it wrong. Gonna test it with double s.

Comment: Try fixing the spelling and see if that makes a difference. See also https://stevencotterill.com/articles/adding-google-recaptcha-v3-to-a-php-form

Comment: It still says the same for some reason.

Comment: I add a var dump and this is what I got: ```object(stdClass)#2 (2) { ["success"]=> bool(false) ["error-codes"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(22) "missing-input-response" } } You are a Robot! :(``` what can cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple basic troubleshooting things to ensure first:

1. Make sure you're using your correct reCAPTCHA Site Key and reCAPTCHA Secret Key values from Google.
2. Also, make sure you are serving the PHP file from one of the domains you chose when you registered for your reCAPTCHA keys.

If both of those are in order, the following steps should work (I just tried them on my end). *Important: Don't forget to replace the placeholder strings with your actual site/secret keys!*

**1.** Include the reCAPTCHA v3 API script in your HTML. Make sure you include your reCAPTCHA Site Key:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=YOUR_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY"></script>
```

**2.** Include the following script:

```
<script>
    grecaptcha.ready(function () {
        grecaptcha.execute('YOUR_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY', { action: 'contact' }).then(function (token) {
            let recaptchaResponse = document.getElementById('recaptchaResponse');
            recaptchaResponse.value = token;
        });
    });
</script>
```

**3.** Here's an example form for you to try:

```
<form method="POST">

    <label class="label">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="input" placeholder="Name" required>

    <label class="label">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="input" placeholder="Email Address" required>
                          
    <label class="label">Message</label>
    <textarea name="message" class="textarea" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>

    <button type="submit">Send</button>
                            
    <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response" id="recaptchaResponse">

</form>
```

**4.** On the server-side, you can process the form like this:

```
<?php

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST" && isset($_POST["recaptcha_response"])) {

        // Create POST request to send to Google
        $recaptcha_url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
        $recaptcha_secret = "YOUR_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY";
        $recaptcha_response = $_POST["recaptcha_response"];

        // Send POST request
        $recaptcha = file_get_contents($recaptcha_url . "?secret=" . $recaptcha_secret . "&response=" . $recaptcha_response);
        
        // Decode response
        $recaptcha = json_decode($recaptcha);

        // Check if verified
        if ($recaptcha->success && $recaptcha->score >= 0.5) {
            // Verified
            echo("Success!");
        } else {
            // Not verified, i.e., a robot?
            echo("Failed!");
        }

    } 
?>
```

**So, putting it all together**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=YOUR_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY"></script>

        <script>
            grecaptcha.ready(function () {
                grecaptcha.execute('YOUR_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY', { action: 'contact' }).then(function (token) {
                    let recaptchaResponse = document.getElementById('recaptchaResponse');
                    recaptchaResponse.value = token;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Enter the form from above here -->
        <!-- Enter the PHP from above here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

...and save that as some `filename.php`. You should get the result back when you submit the form.

Comment: Should I let this as "contact"? ```{ action: 'contact' }```

Comment: It works fine with your solution, thanks for your help. I didn't change that action, looks like I don't have to.

Comment: This link explains the purpose of the action parameter (it's mainly for your own benefit): https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3#actions